# How to configure a site-specific custom caret color for Dark Reader?

Tags: css, google-chrome

For script.google.com, I can make the entire page site dark, but when I do, I cannot see the cursor/caret.  I've found the developer tools for Dark Reader, but I can't seem to figure out the CSS to configure the cursor to be white.

I've tried adding this via the Developer Tools, but I still cannot see the caret:

```
================================

script.google.com

INVERT
.docs-icon
.icon

CSS
html, body, input, text, textarea, select, button, div {
   caret-color: red;
}

================================
```

How can I configure a site-specific custom cursor/caret color in Dark Reader?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with formulas on Google Sheets where. I ended up selecting a parent element with an id and assigning caret-color to #000 so Dark Reader would change it to #FFF on all instances.

Answer (score 0):

caret color

```
.monaco-editor.cursors-layer.cursor {
background-color: #cccccc !important;
border-color: #cccccc !important; 
color: #ffffff !important;}
```

UPD: it turns out that Dark Reader already has this update

```
================================

script.google.com

INVERT
.docs-icon
.icon
.monaco-editor .cursors-layer > .cursor

IGNORE INLINE STYLE
mask > *

================================
```